# jqPlot not rendering

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I copy-and-pasted jqPlot code from the official website word for word and I got it to work inside an ajax call. 
Now, when I use data I received via my ajax call, I can't get it to render correctly anymore....

Literal string being passed back from AJAX:

```
[["2014/01/16 12:00:00 AM","215"],["2014/01/14 12:00:00 AM","225"],["2014/01/13 12:00:00 AM","219"],["2014/01/12 12:00:00 AM","218"],["2014/01/11 12:00:00 AM","220"]]
```

My ajax success call:

```
success: function (data) {
                    alert(data)

                    var plot2 = $.jqplot('weightChart', [data], {
                        title: 'Customized Date Axis',
                        gridPadding: { right: 35 },
                        axes: {
                            xaxis: {
                                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                tickOptions: { formatString: '%b %#d, %y' },
                                min: 'May 30, 2013',
                                tickInterval: '1 month'
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{ lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
                    });
                }
```

Not sure what the problem is. Thanks all

EDIT:

I just created a a hardcoded array and used that in my jqplot call, and it worked. However, the data coming through the ajax call did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is data type of data string or json

Comment: text .. string ....from c#. using javascriptserializer

Comment: can you add your data to the question

Comment: It may be the problem that my second values are being passed as strings and not an int, how would I go about that?

Comment: The string in the first block of code, is the data being alerted inside the success function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've tried your code, and it works.
The strange thing is that you are using data which covers a period of a week
in a range on the x-axis of about 6 months! Your data starts from Jan 2014 but you
set the min value to May 2013.
Furthermore, the values are all around 220 values and in the jqplot chart
not always the autoscale works well (often when you are using a date format).

So i made some changes:

```
xaxis: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
    tickOptions: { formatString: '%b %#d, %y' },
    //min: 'May 30, 2013',
    min: 'Dec 30, 2013',
    tickInterval: '1 week'
},
yaxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 300        
}
```

and i hope this could help you with handling your data. The following figure is the result.
[image]

Comment: Seems like the data coming back from my ajax call is the reasons for the problem. Not sure why though

Comment: Is the canvas of jqPlot that doesn't appears? or what you see is a chart with wrong data visualization? If is the first case, maybe you didn't write the correct target in the <div> tag, a bad synchronizazion between the ajax call and the visualization of the chart, (remember if you don't manage right the call, before show the chart and then read the data...)  or else... in the second case, check with console.log() the format of data coming with the ajax call and see if it is the same of the data reported above. If they are the same, of course, the data are not your problem.